# Returning a query to display ads on side bar

Tags: ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am working with three tables `Salon` `Treatment` and `Service`. `Service` is owned by `Salon`. `Service` and `Treatment` have a direct relationship as every `Service` has a `Treatment` but not every `Treatment` has a `Service`. Treatment holds a variable `Category`.

I am trying to display results on a side bar of the `treatments/show`of all Services related to the `Treatment` they are looking at.

In my `application helper` I have the following query

def salonAds

```
@ads = Services.includes(:treatment).where('treatment.category = ?',  Service[:treatment_id])

end
```

But I know that is wrong.

I am them trying to call a `do` in my `treatments/show`

```
<% @ads.each do |ads| %>
<td><%= ads.description %></td>
    <td><%= ads.price %></td>

   <% end %>
```

Any solutions or alternatives to how this can be achieved would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

You could make a join table for `services_treatments` and then change the relationship between `Service` and `Treatment` to `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Then when you want to assign services to the treatment you would add it to the `service_ids` column on the `Treatment model`.

Then when you wanted all the services for a treatment you would do:

```
Treatment.find(params[:id]).services
```